# Aligning single button in menu using css

Tags: css, menu

I am working on a site and am trying for ages to create a menu that has regular buttons on the left and one single button on the right. It seems that no matter what I try Nothing works! It's a basic `ul li` with some style and float, but no matter what I try I can't move just one `li` to the right, what should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Mike's answer, this would be better as there is no need to position it absolute, as you are already using floats on it, you can just float one element to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/v6vq8/2/

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">button 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">button 2</a></li>
  <li class="standout"><a href="#">button 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">button 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">button 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu li {float:left;}
.menu a {display: block; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 3px 5px; margin: 0 2px;}
.menu .standout { float:right; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't even know what I've done different, but it works. I have another question on the subject that I could use some help with, if you will. In the homepage, I want the entire menu to be placed in the middle of the page, and on other pages fixed to the top. I tried using a div but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: No problem, if you could mark as accepted that would be great :) As for aligning the menu middle, try a bit of research first then create a new question if you are really struggling and link it here

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry I'm new here :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `absolute position` on your list element to take out the item from the flow and put it on the right.

```
.menu { overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.menu li { float: left; list-style: none outside none; margin: 0 2px; }
.menu a { display: block; background: #333; color: #fff; padding: 3px 5px; }

.menu .standout { right: 0; position: absolute; } // remove item from flow and put it on the right
```

Here is an example on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6vq8/) that could help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! It seemed to work for a while and then got messed up, I have no idea why.